# Nested Ticket Edit Action Comes Up Blank Inside Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a rails app to learn about nested controllers actions. Hence I have `Projects` to which `Tickets` are nested underneath. It's basically a rip-off from Rails Action. Now, I am trying to add edit action in Ticket's controller.

Everything works fine in Projects, ie, all the actions.

Everything seems to work fine in Tickets. As stated earlier, it's a rip-off from Rails Action. So trying learn how to put in correct stuff within blank actions, ie, `Edit`, `Show`, `Update`, and `Destroy`

When I added edit action in `Tickets` show page, and clicked on it, it showed the page, but the form fields are blank.

The url path is correct: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/projects/2/tickets/2/edit` so that means the resources are set up correctly.

How do I fix this so it shows the previous content? My vague understanding is that it may have to do with the form?

**Current Tickets Controller**

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController

    #which actions are necessary? learn how to not need set_project set_ticket
    before_action :set_project
    before_action :set_ticket, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def create 
        @ticket = @project.tickets.build(ticket_params) 

        if @ticket.save
            flash[:notice] = "Ticket has been created." 
            redirect_to project_path(@project)
        else
            flash.now[:alert] = "Ticket has not been created."
            render "new"
        end
    end 

    def new 
        @ticket = @project.tickets.build
    end

    def show
    end

    def edit 
        @ticket = @project.tickets.find(params[:id]) 
    end

    def update
    end

    def destroy
    end


    private 

        def ticket_params
            params.require(:ticket).permit(:title, :description)
        end

        def set_project 
            @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
        end

        def set_ticket 
            @ticket = @project.tickets.find(params[:id]) 
        end

end
```

**show.html.erb - Ticket**

```
<h1><%= @project.title %></h1>

<h3><%= @ticket.title %></h3>

<%= link_to "All Projects", projects_path %>

<%= link_to "Edit Ticket", edit_project_ticket_path %>
```

**_form.html.erb - Ticket**

```
<%= form_for([@project, @project.tickets.build]) do |f| %>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :description %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :description %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>

<% end %>
```

**EDIT, I've updated the _form.html.erb to the following code beneath, and it seems to work, ie, it shows the contents to modify. Yay. But when I click on `Update Ticket` button, it doesn't move beyond the page.**

```
<%= form_for [@project,@ticket] do |f| %>
```

**EDIT AGAIN**

I updated the ticket's controller actions for `Show` and `Update`, and now it seems to work! Including it for feedback in case this was done incorrectly.

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController

    #which actions are necessary? learn how to not need set_project set_ticket
    before_action :set_project
    before_action :set_ticket, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def create 
        @ticket = @project.tickets.build(ticket_params) 

        if @ticket.save
            flash[:notice] = "Ticket has been created." 
            redirect_to project_path(@project)
        else
            flash.now[:alert] = "Ticket has not been created."
            render "new"
        end
    end 

    def new 
        @ticket = @project.tickets.build
    end

    def show
        @ticket = @project.tickets.find(params[:id]) 
    end

    def edit 
        @ticket = @project.tickets.find(params[:id]) 
    end

def update
  if @ticket.update(ticket_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Ticket has been updated."
    redirect_to [@project, @ticket]
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "Ticket has not been updated."
    render "edit"
  end
end

    def destroy
    end


    private 

        def ticket_params
            params.require(:ticket).permit(:title, :description)
        end

        def set_project 
            @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
        end

        def set_ticket 
            @ticket = @project.tickets.find(params[:id]) 
        end

end
```

Comment: Because build will generate a new object every time it's called. `build` method basically generates a skeleton object empty from class and every time you are rendering ticket form it is doing that...

Comment: @Mayank, so what should the `<%= form_for([@project, @project.tickets.build]) do |f| %>` be then? Because I've tried `<%= form_for([@project, @project.tickets]) do |f| %>` and I get `NoMethodError in Tickets#edit` and `undefined method 'to_key' for #<Ticket::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fa0cfea2410>`

Comment: @Mayank, I've also tried this: `<%= form_for(@project, @project.tickets) do |f| %>`, and I get this error: `TypeError in Tickets#edit` and `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`